# Installing Typesafe activator on OSX

Tags: macos, path, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to install the typesafe activator (scala, AKKA, play framework, activator)

I have Yosemite OSX

My bash is Oh my ZSH

I already have JDK 1.7, installed and exported

I downloaded and unzipped the file "typesafe-activator-1.2.10-minimal". Finally I put the export path on my ~/.zshrc

but when I type activator on the terminal it prints that cant find the file

thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made a big mistake, In the ~/.zshrc where I should put

`export PATH=$PATH:/relativePath/to/activator`

I added the executable file to the path. I post this answer in case is helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 41):

get [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/).
play documentation says this : 
[Play install on mac](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/install)

But there have been some changes to that. Now you have to do this.

Try this:

```
brew install typesafe-activator
```

And then use `activator` command to start it

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Refer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/57029518/154325

Answer (score 6):

For people like me, who are reading this in 2019 (or later) and are [unable to find activator recipee](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/39711) in homebrew, be informed that [activator has been decommissioned](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator)

Good news is, it's fairly simple to [create new projects](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html) (including templates for play, akka etc.) with `sbt new` command and Giter8 templates.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and follow the below steps,

```html
mkdir ~/bin

ln -s <path to your play home>/activator ~/bin

echo "export PATH=~/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc

. ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

These days, in 2020, it seems Activator isn't available from Homebrew anymore?

But old Activator releases remain downloadable, from e.g. https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.6/typesafe-activator-1.3.6.zip. (I assume other version numbers work as well.)

Answer (score -1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/XXX/XXX/activator-dist-1.3.12/bin
```

Comment: What is difference from other answer?