# how to get typesafe-activator 1.3.6 on mac

Tags: scala

When trying to install typesafe-activator using below command

brew install typesafe-activator, I get an error not available.

```
    brew install typesafe-activator
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 3 formulae.
==> New Casks
dropbox-passwords
==> Updated Casks
aws-vault               bunch                   clockify                fantastical             gitkraken               mactracker              popo                    shift                   syncthing               vellum
balenaetcher            caprine                 electrum                fitbit-os-simulator     grandtotal              marvin                  progressive-downloader  signal                  thebrain                workflowy
brave-browser           clash-for-windows       epichrome               futuniuniu              jami                    odrive                  qownnotes               studio-3t               usenapp                 wormhole

Error: No available formula with the name "brew" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
brew-cask-completion                    brew-gem                                brew-php-switcher                       brew-pip                                nodebrew                                whalebrew
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install brew-cask-completion
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps
```

Will someone point out how can I install typesafe-activator on mac?

Comment: Is `brew install brew install typesafe-activator` the command you are running, or `brew install typesafe-activator`?

Comment: i am running brew install typesafe-activator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Typesafe activator on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771638/installing-typesafe-activator-on-osx)

Comment: i used  that only but  i am not able to fetch it using brew

Comment: `activator` has been replaced by `sbt new` templates https://stackoverflow.com/a/57029518/5205022

Comment: Old Activator releases remain downloadable, from e.g. https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.6/typesafe-activator-1.3.6.zip